# Comparing different deep learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

Does anyone know a paper that describes the differences and compares the different deep learning architectures? like Stacked autoencoders, deep believe networks, maxout networks ... etc.

Answer (score 4):

[Bengio's review of representation learining](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5538v3.pdf) is probably as close as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good resource I use for comparison - their performance on different benchmark datasets.

[This is an excellent site](http://rodrigob.github.io/are_we_there_yet/build/classification_datasets_results.html) that does that has an ordered results of most of the noteworthy papers.

Take note of the "details" button on the right column, It gives a short description on their testing methodology, for example if an ensemble was used, what type of augmentation, etc.

A word of advice, the best thing you can do is **try it yourself**. From my personal experience, significant part of the performance difference published in deep learning papers has to do with training knowhow - proper choice of hyperparameters and augmentation than the actual architecture. sad but true.

**UPDATE:**
The site I posted now seems to be less frequently updated. I would humbly still suggest it as an excellent starting point. But I suggest all avid explorers to look further into citations of these original papers to see how the research evolved.